# Datastax - Cassandra PHP Driver - Execute CQL script

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-php-driver

Using Datastax - Cassandra PHP Driver, I would like execute CQL script file. For example, this script file contain many CREATE KEYSPACE,CREATE TABLE commands.

In cqlsh terminal, I can do the above thing by

```
cqlsh>source 'script_name.cql';
```

But, How I can acheive the same through  Datastax - Cassandra PHP Driver?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API in driver. Same can be achieved through:

1. If cql is installed on the server where php is being run, then use `exec(cqlsh [ other optional options ] -f script_name.cql)`.
2. Read the file in PHP code and execute the command.

Comment: Thank You Very much. I have tested your suggestion and found working.